# @PostConstruct used with Jersey 1.17, Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, weblogic, jax-rs

I expose some statistics data as REST service using Jersey.
I am using Weblogic

However each time when I execute a request to get statistics 
System.out.println("In PostConstruct"); is called.

This happens even if i annotate beside path @Stateless.

This behaves like  StorageService is instantiated on each request (req scope)

Is there a way to have initialize called only once and avoid creating StorageService on each request ?

```
@Path("/statistics")
public class StorageService {

    @Context
    private ServletContext application;

    StatisticsStorage statisticsStorage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("In PostConstruct");
        try {
            statisticsStorage = new StatisticsStorage((String) application.getAttribute(AppProperties.PropKey.STATS_OUTPUT_PATH_PROP.toString()));
        } catch (Exception sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @GET
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Domain getSnapshot() {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default "scope" of JAX-RS resource classes is a per-request scope. We can also register the the class as a singleton. Different JAX-RS implementations may have different way this can be accomplished. For example Apache Wink has a `@Scope(ScopeType.SINGLETON)`. But the only portable way is to use an [`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass. Something like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
        singletons.add(new StorageService());
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Everything returned in the `getClasses()` will be a per-request resource. And `getSingletons()` will return resources that are "application scoped". Jersey will never try to instantiate the class, so we can handle all the initialization ourselves.

- See more deployment options at [Deploying a RESTful Web Service](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e188)

On another note, you may want to consider, if making this class a singleton is what you really want. By doing this, it will cause the resource class to be stateful and you will need to handle any concurrency issues.

If all you want to do in the `@PostConstruct` is create the `StatisticsStorage`, maybe a better option is to use an injection framwork, like [Guice](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e1876) for instance. Here's a [good Guice example(s)](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes//posts/jersey_guice_rest_api). Or EE's CDI

Answer (score 2):

Jersey instantiates the class on every request. Note that most of the things you can annotate with @Context are request-specific. Your best bet is to make your StatisticsStorage field static and initialize it on the first request (will require synchronization). Maybe something like this:

```
public StorageService(@Context ServletContext application) {
    super(servletConfig, request, httpServletRequest, uriInfo, httpHeaders, securityContext);
    synchronized (this.getClass()) {
        if (statisticsStorage == null) {
            try {
                statisticsStorage = new StatisticsStorage((String) application.getAttribute(AppProperties.PropKey.STATS_OUTPUT_PATH_PROP.toString()));
            } catch (Exception sqle) {
                sqle.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
static StatisticsStorage statisticsStorage;
```